# Show results depending on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am building a landlord mgt application. But I am having an issue - I only want to index requests where the `house.id` (association value) matches the current user.

Currently, I have got it to work depending if the user has created it. But I would like the landlord to see all requests that are related to their properties.

requests_controller.rb:

```
def index
  unless current_user.estate_agent?
    @requests = Request.where(user_id: current_user).search(params[:search])
  else
    @requests = Request.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

request.rb

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :house

  def self.search(search)
    key = "%#{search}%"
    if search
      where('description LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?', key, key)
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

house.rb

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tenant
  has_many :requests
  belongs_to :contract

  mount_uploader :energy, EnergyUploader

  validates_presence_of :house_title, :description, :doorno, :postcode, :price, :bedroom, :house_type

  def full_house_name
   "#{doorno} #{house_title}"
  end

  def self.search(search)
    key = "%#{search}%"
    if search
      where('doorno LIKE ? OR house_title LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? OR postcode LIKE ? OR house_type LIKE ? OR bedroom LIKE ?', key, key, key, key, key, key)
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show your model relationship

Comment: Try not to do an `unless` with an `else`, as that's a double negative. Instead use an `if` and reverse the order of the blocks. You'll also want to indent your code properly as right now it's all jumbled and hard to read, structurally speaking.

Comment: @widjajayd added both models, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to show all requests that were made by the user or made for his real-state.

The code below will create your initial filter, then you can call your `search` method over it.

```
Request.where(user_id: current_user.id).or(Request.where(house: { user_id: current_user.id}))
```

Comment: Thanks @merehghost. I tried this but get a undefined error on the (or) part